# How to move fast after fetching data from api on pressing button Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I want to ask if there is a future function who gives data from api and i want to get that data when i pressed the button and i want some particular data like id of user i am using function like

```
onPressed: () async {
     var data = await getLogin()
     if(data.id == 0){
       Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) => Login())));
     else {
        Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) => Order())));
      }
}
```

Can you tell me why it is taking time when i am pressing button to open new screen and can any one tell me the solution

Answer (score 0):

it is taking time because it `await` for data. It is a async function and this await keyword wait until you didn't get the data back..

Problem is that if you not use await keyword then data.id throw a null safety error....

So solution is Future Provider... Call the api using the any state management solution like provider and navigate without checking the condition... Then update Ui after getting data from Provider..

Comment: I am using setState so tell me that it will cause problem on changing state or i will use other state management that you said provider